# Cartan subalgebra and Casimir invariants

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

To my understanding, if group $G$ is semisimple, $\mathfrak{g}$ is its Lie algebra, and $\Delta_T=[T,\cdot]$ is the adjoint representation, one can analyze its spectrum with $[T,U]=\lambda U$.
A particularly important value is $R=\inf_{T\in\mathfrak{g}}deg(\lambda=0)$, since there are (at most) **R communing generators of $\mathfrak{g}$** and **R Casimir invariants**. Now,

- the {$C_1,...,C_R$} commuting generators are the generators of a subalgebra called *Cartan's subalgebra*, which is interesting because its structure constants are zero: $[C_i,C_j]=0 \space\forall \space i,j$;
- the {$H_1,...,H_R$} Casimir invariants are defined by the fact that they commute with all the generators of $\mathfrak{g}$.

My question: are $C_i$ and $H_i$ the same? Maybe under some hypotheses? It seems at least plausible, since they both are R independent operators, and they both have banal commutators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same. The Casimir invariants $\{H_1,\ldots,H_R\}$ (in your notation) generate the center $Z(U\mathfrak{g})$ of $U\mathfrak{g}$, the [universal enveloping algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra) of $\mathfrak{g}$, and involve terms that are of order $\ge 2$ in $\mathfrak{g}$. The elements $\{C_1,\ldots,C_R\}$ are elements of $\mathfrak{g}$. The fact that the cardinality of these two generating sets agree is a non-trivial result.